# Can I save my Firefox tabs?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, data-loss-prevention

Here's the situation:

I have around 50 Firefox tabs open with reading material about programming and it took me a while to organize and find all the links. The weekend is finally here and I was going to go through all of them and now.. Firefox is crashing (kinda)

I opened a link to [dotnetrocks.com](http://dotnetrocks.com) and while loading the tab Firefox locked up and now the application is hanging.

However, Firefox is still "working" in the sense that I had a starcraft stream in one of the tabs and the audio is still playing just fine. Everything was working fine. It's just the loading of that one tab halted the rest of the application for some reason.

Why not just kill the process and restore the tabs when I reopen Firefox? Well, I apparently thought it was a great idea a while ago not to have Firefox save my history (because if I want to look at something later on, I'll just bookmark it. Why needlessly save everything?) Obviously now I'm kicking myself for that decision.

Why not just take a picture of all the tabs? Well, I use [treestyletabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) and the majority of the tabs are nested under one tab, so they are not visible in Firefox's current state.

At this point I really wish I was using Chrome because each of each tab being a separate process so one tab crashing wouldn't crash the whole program. Is there a way to "kill" off a tab in Firefox while it's in this crashing state? At this point I don't think Firefox is coming back because I've been waiting for this tab to load for 10 minutes now and it's still hanging the application.

A rather odd and specific question, I know. There's probably nothing I can do at this point but who knows, maybe some genius can help me out with this rather unfortunate situation I've gotten myself in to. Not sure if this kind of question is suitable to this site or where else I would put it..

Comment: Oh, in Chrome one tab can just as well chrash the whole program as well. Glad to know it worked (what you did); although needless to say, 50 tabs is a bit too much. (I often have 30 open, so it's not "that far", but I notice my machine gets very sluggy then, expecially if I have to work in anything more demanding than Word or Excel simultaneously).

Comment: If you're gonna keep this question alive, better post the answer from your edit as an answer, and accept it in a day or two. That way the question's gonna get "closed", and not reappearing over and over again.

Comment: It's better to put them as bookmarks because you're not likely to be using the 50 tabs at once. I find it quite useless to have a ton tabs open when you're actually surfing 5 max at once.

Comment: I've forced myself into the habit of using a task list to add pages that I will want to read later, instead of leaving the tabs open. I try to close my browser at the end of each day. I say try - because I often still end up leaving stuff open over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer:

> Edit: I saved them! Not sure how exactly. I went through my list of
>   processes and firstly killed the plugin-container for firefox. There
>   were a couple of them and I killed them all. Then I just killed a lot
>   of other non-vital processes that were running and (if only to free up
>   memory, perhaps) and then killed and relaunched explorer.exe and at
>   that point the application was restored.